# Defining a struct along with a str dictionary using a macro

Tags: c, dictionary, struct, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to automatise the generation of struct in my code for which the syntax is specify by the [Midas Library](https://daq00.triumf.ca/MidasWiki/index.php/Main_Page). The difficulty here lies in the parallel building of `const char*` dictionary that mimic the struct definition:

```cpp
typedef struct {
  BOOL      runColdStartScript;
  BOOL      runPedestalScript;
  BOOL      triggerCommunicationTest;
  BOOL      updateOdbParameters;
  BOOL      runCmdBuffer;
  BOOL      runSelectedScript;
} myHotLink;
myHotLink hotLinkContainer{};
const char *hot_links_str[9] = { \
  "[.]", \
  "runColdStartScript = BOOL : n", \
  "runPedestalScript = BOOL : n", \
  "triggerCommunicationTest = BOOL : n", \
  "updateOdbParameters = BOOL : n", \
  "runCmdBuffer = BOOL : n", \
  "runSelectedScript = BOOL : n", \
  "", nullptr 
};
```

Ideally I'd like to generate this piece of code with a macro. For example:

```c
MAKE_HOT_LINK(
  myHotLink,
  { BOOL, runColdStartScript, n },
  { BOOL, runPedestalScript, n },
  ...
)
```

Does someone have an idea on how to define (and properly call) the `MAKE_HOT_LINK` macro?

Cheers!

Comment: Have a look at _`##` tokenizer_. Might come handy.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example on how this could be used?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. Should I remove the C++ tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some metamacros to define the fields you want and some other macros that expand those to the declaration and descriptor:

```
#define MYHOTLINK_FIELDS(M) \
    M(BOOL, runColdStartScript, n) \
    M(BOOL, runPedestalScript, n) \
    M(BOOL, triggerCommunicationTest, n) \
    M(BOOL, updateOdbParameters, n) \
    M(BOOL, runCmdBuffer, n) \
    M(BOOL, runSelectedScript, n) \

#define FIELD_DECL(TYPE, NAME, TAG)  TYPE NAME;
#define FIELD_DESCRIPTOR(TYPE, NAME, TAG)   #NAME " = " #TYPE " : " #TAG,

#define DECLARE_STRUCT(STYPE) struct { STYPE(FIELD_DECL) }
#define STRUCT_DESCRIPTOR(STYPE) { "[.]", STYPE(FIELD_DESCRIPTOR) "", nullptr }

typedef DECLARE_STRUCT(MYHOTLINK_FIELDS) myHotLink;
myHotLink hotLinkContainer {};
const char *hot_links_str[] = STRUCT_DESCRIPTOR(MYHOTLINK_FIELDS);
```

would expand to (equivalent of) what you have above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a viable solution :). So the only way to define this bond of three elements is through a metamacro?